# Which statistic (econometric) technique to use to estimate index for panel data?

Tags: pca, panel-data

I have panel data set with 25 id's (cities) and 3 years of observations. Data set contain 10 variables of economic development.

I would like to make an index that would "compress" 10 variables in index of economic development.

Which statistic method is best suited for this problem? I was thinking about PCA, but I am not sure can I use it on panel data set. Also I have only 25 observations for every year (altogether 75 observations).

My goal is just to construct an index. I would not use it latter as dependent or independent variable in further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would be best off generating the principal components of the 10 variables for each of the 25 cities independently. Due to differences in local economic conditions, it would make sense for there to be variation in the co-movement of the independent variables.  If the first component explains a good portion of the variation, then you could track the first component over time for the 25 cities and observe variations in trends.